# Activity Tab in Profile: `overlay` in `reputationGraph` widens when in Documentation tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, activity-tab

The reputation indicator seems to widen in the Documentation tab, https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=documentation.

**Normal width:**

[image: Image 1]

**Width when in Documentation tab:**

[image: Image 2]

The code for both remains the same:

```
<rect class="overlay" width="139" height="50"></rect>
```

User agent:

**Browser:** Safari Version 10.0.1
**OS:** macOS Sierra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report! The width will be consistent across all tabs starting with the next prod build.